# Populate a Listbox from a string with values separated by commas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string that is populated by the user choosing from a list of values, which I will output later, but I want to populate a listbox with each value so the user can see the values they've selected.

```
Example: poString = ('PO_ORDERID','PO_ORDERNO')
List box: PO_ORDERID
          PO_ORDERNO
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to populate a userform listbox with each value in the string.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Split` method:

```
With ListBox1
    .Clear
    .List = Split(poString, ",")
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Use split to populate a listbox from a string (It converts a string to an array):

```
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Split("Hello,World,A,Test,Entry", ",")
```

Replace the string with your string variable and keep the comma as the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated if the listbox is from a ActiveX control or UserForm, this should work regardless

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            .AddItem c
        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a user form. And its from a string not a range of cells. Sorry about that.